# Laravel Spatie permissions best way to add multiple roles to check against user roles for multiple models

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-permission

I'm working inside a Laravel 10 project that uses the Laravel Spatie Permissions package v5.9.1. My Laravel project is used as an API that outputs stuff to a Nuxt JS front-end, including a menu.

Super admins of my platform can create a menu, and assign menu items to it, each menu item also has a potential of being a nested menu item, this equates to having two models:

- `Menu`
- `MenuItem`

Ideally, I don't want to have multiple menus with potentially hundreds, if not thousands of menu items, I ideally want to check that a user's role means that they have access to view a particular menu item.

How might I do this?

Here's my current database tables of `menus` and `menu_items`
[image]

[image]

My menu is brought via a slug to my page via:

```php
/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'slug' => 'required|exists:menus,slug',
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return new ApiValidationErrorResponse($validator->messages());
    }

    $menu = MenuItem::tree()
                    ->whereRelation('menu', 'slug', $request->input('slug'))
                    ->where('is_enabled', true)
                    ->orderBy('display_order', 'asc')
                    ->get()
                    ->toTree();

    if (! $menu || count($menu) <= 0) {
        return new ApiSuccessResponse(null, [
            'message' => 'No menu found for your company.',
        ], 404);
    }

    return new ApiSuccessResponse($menu);
}
```